# fo:region-body columns headers in xslfo

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo

I'm new to xsl fo and here is my problem:

I declare a fo:region-body with two columns

```
<fo:region-body column-count="2" />
```

Is there a way for these 2 columns to have a header?
If it is possible, can I change the text of the header dynamically?

In fact, in the source XML, I have several category followed by some text, and I wish to recall the category on each new column of my layout.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The columns of the page layout are not columns in the sense of tables. Do you mean having a paragraph on top of the page that spans both columns?

Comment: In fact, I mean having a paragraph on top of each columns

Comment: Have you tried using break-before="column" on the block containing your header text? As Mathias points out, these aren't like table columns. But that might get you the effect you want, if the other content in the column never flows into column 2.

Comment: The break-before="column" does not have the desired effect. In fact, I want to "recall" the category on each column.

Answer (score 0):

Put the actual "column" headers in the region-before (like use a two column, one row simple table at the bottom of the region-before). Then use markers in the content flow, marking what you desire. Inside that table in the region-before, retrieve the markers to make the headers dynamic (based on some content on that page).

Another option (although it would depend on what content you wish in the header), would be to use an actual table structure in the two column flow. Just a table with a single row, single cell and a header. Of course, you do not need to apply borders or anything to this. This would be more limiting and it would require more samples of what exactly is being placed into that header. The first option above is much more generic.

Comment: I try to use the marker and retrieve-marker, but all I manage to do is to recall the last category title of each "column" headers. Maybe if I post an example it would help?

Comment: Yes, post an example of what you want. Markers will only help if the headers are driven by two different things (like first on page and last on page). Otherwise its possible a table-based solution works with a single table cell and header cell that repeats. I need to see an example of what you want though.